# How to measure the width of a string using Fable or Feliz in an Elmish app?

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

In an Elmish app (using Fable and Feliz), I'm trying to create a container (a `div`) with the exact width as an arbitrary string. Is there a way to measure the width of a string ahead of time (before displaying it)?

Comment: Given than Fable just translates F# to JS, it should help to use JS answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: This should do the trick: https://fable.io/repl/#?code=LYewJgrgNgpgBAIQIYGcCWBjAwkgdgN1QCgiQAHGXRAJxAHcUZqA6AFQE8KVSKqFaGTErAAucNLjQiAFAEo4AXiJwVcUXAx5CKRXDAgMEYJRHMAjhCbsAyjFgYRIatIBEzfGhh0X8gFwB+AD44AAlWAFkAGRwCVABRWGNcEWVVdQcAD11NWJRmAHMYESwQZJgMkQB9ACYwOVSVTOYAM1KxAB4AWjgXACMQKDA4aoAGMiykajQkKBcGjREMlrQoKFZysWkm41QIahh1itczOhgfZjo0MBEACzYQaxEp3Hy5ABo4AEYRkY-vkdkJAkUnqQA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAUHUBTAhgE3gAm54ElgqbhgAOAtEgI4CuAlgG4C8ARAMID2AdmEj+QBUAnqSQtMAY268erXgA8wAenDQA3BJAoATgGcCTGmABm5ABwt4wFagwJgAIw5ohWHMAkouDFLslRfXVYGOiQAd3EwujQwEFYAFgAGRPEQJDoAc3AE5MtrT29fKyUnF3hEFUhYOCA&css=Q

Comment: Can you use CSS [`width: fit-content;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)?

Comment: @BrianBerns The problem with that is that I believe I need to show the contents of what is being fit. I don't want to show the actual string (at least not at first).

Comment: @JL0PD Thank you, that did the trick. However, I wish I didn't have to set the font manually but instead detect it automatically based on the containing element.

Comment: @redcurry, linked answer contains example of text size for specific element. Author called that method `getCanvasFont`